# Bing Static Map Image type

Tags: static, dictionary, bing-maps

May I know how to determine the output of Bing map static image? Previously it used to be in png but now it is in jpeg. May I know how to revert back to png format?

Example: Display the image with the link below:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Road/space%20needle,seattle?mapLayer=TrafficFlow&mapVersion=v1&key=BingKey

The image is in jpeg. How to make it to png? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can request the image in a different format.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx :

> This URL returns an image in one of
>   the following formats:
>
> - PNG (image/png)
> - JPEG (image/jpeg)
> - GIF (image/gif)
>
> You cannot specify the output format
>   for the map image. The image type is
>   chosen based on parameters such as
>   imagerySet.

If you really want a PNG, you could make the request from a server-side script and then construct a PNG file programmatically before serving that back to the client (using PHP's [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) function, for example)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a while you posted this question, but as there is no answer yet, and I got here via Google I'll supply an answer anyway.

You can use the format / fmt parameter.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

> One of the following image format values:
>
> 1. gif: Use GIF image format.
> 2. jpeg: Use JPEG image format. JPEG format is the default for Road, Aerial and AerialWithLabels imagery.
> 3. png: Use PNG image format. PNG is the default format for CollinsBart and OrdnanceSurvey imagery.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> format=jpeg
>
> fmt=gif