# How can I access Traffic layer of google maps in Python 2.7?

Tags: google-maps, python-2.7

to access and display google maps i used the following code:

```
    import pylab
    from cStringIO import StringIO
    from PIL import Image
    import urllib

    url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=12.955232,77.579923&size=600x600&zoom=17&sensor=false"
    buffer = StringIO(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
    image = Image.open(buffer)
    pylab.imshow(image)
    pylab.show()
```

but I am not able to find a way to add the traffic layer to this image.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You used to load traffic into the static map by adding `&layer=t`.

Since the API version v2 came out, this property has been removed.
For now, there is no alternative, other than using another map provider.

Comment: Can you please suggest which would be the **best alternative** and whether I can use the older API version having this feature in anyway? thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know if you can use another version of the API. Bing static map seems to have the property &mapLayer=trafficFlow. A quick search turned this up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205006/bing-static-map-image-type

Comment: is there a solution to this